Getting 404 AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404
Could you please help me to solve the problem with the routes.
In result I have the next code:
// server/index.js
// server/index.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/users');
const abiturientRoutes = require('./routes/abiturients'); // Добавили

const app = express();
const PORT = 5000;

// Middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Маршруты
app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/api/users', userRoutes);
app.use('/api/abiturients', abiturientRoutes); // Добавили

// Запуск сервера
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

Then I got the following code
//server/routes/abiturients.js
//server/routes/abiturients.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const pool = require('../db/connection');

// Получение всех абитуриентов
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const [rows] = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM abiturients');
        res.json(rows);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error fetching abiturients' });
    }
});

// Создание нового абитуриента
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const { full_name, gender, recommended_by, education_level, available_specialty, previous_educational_institution, phone_number, date_added, desired_education_level, desired_specialty, specialization, study_form, student_status, notes, questionnaire_date, gunp_call_date, document_submission_date, medical_commission_completion_date, vlk_start_date, vlk_end_date, evi_efvv_registration_date, documents } = req.body;
    
    try {
        const sql = `
            INSERT INTO abiturients (
                full_name, gender, recommended_by, education_level, available_specialty, 
                previous_educational_institution, phone_number, date_added, 
                desired_education_level, desired_specialty, specialization, study_form, 
                student_status, notes, questionnaire_date, gunp_call_date, 
                document_submission_date, medical_commission_completion_date, 
                vlk_start_date, vlk_end_date, evi_efvv_registration_date, documents
            ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        `;
        
        const [result] = await pool.query(sql, [
            full_name, gender, recommended_by, education_level, available_specialty, 
            previous_educational_institution, phone_number, date_added, 
            desired_education_level, desired_specialty, specialization, study_form, 
            student_status, notes, questionnaire_date, gunp_call_date, 
            document_submission_date, medical_commission_completion_date, 
            vlk_start_date, vlk_end_date, evi_efvv_registration_date, documents
        ]);

        res.status(201).json({ id: result.insertId });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error adding abiturient:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error adding abiturient' });
    }
});

// Обновление абитуриента по ID
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { 
        full_name, gender, recommended_by, education_level, available_specialty, 
        previous_educational_institution, phone_number, date_added, 
        desired_education_level, desired_specialty, specialization, study_form, 
        student_status, notes, questionnaire_date, gunp_call_date, 
        document_submission_date, medical_commission_completion_date, 
        vlk_start_date, vlk_end_date, evi_efvv_registration_date, documents 
    } = req.body;
    
    const { id } = req.params;
    
    try {
        const sql = `
            UPDATE abiturients SET 
                full_name = ?, gender = ?, recommended_by = ?, education_level = ?, available_specialty = ?, 
                previous_educational_institution = ?, phone_number = ?, date_added = ?, 
                desired_education_level = ?, desired_specialty = ?, specialization = ?, study_form = ?, 
                student_status = ?, notes = ?, questionnaire_date = ?, gunp_call_date = ?, 
                document_submission_date = ?, medical_commission_completion_date = ?, 
                vlk_start_date = ?, vlk_end_date = ?, evi_efvv_registration_date = ?, documents = ?
            WHERE id = ?
        `;
        
        const [result] = await pool.query(sql, [
            full_name, gender, recommended_by, education_level, available_specialty, 
            previous_educational_institution, phone_number, date_added, 
            desired_education_level, desired_specialty, specialization, study_form, 
            student_status, notes, questionnaire_date, gunp_call_date, 
            document_submission_date, medical_commission_completion_date, 
            vlk_start_date, vlk_end_date, evi_efvv_registration_date, documents, id
        ]);

        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Abiturient updated successfully' });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error updating abiturient:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error updating abiturient' });
    }
});

// Удаление абитуриента по ID
router.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await pool.query('DELETE FROM abiturients WHERE id = ?', [req.params.id]);
        res.json({ message: 'Abiturient deleted successfully' });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error deleting abiturient' });
    }
});

module.exports = router;

//src/services/api.js
//src/services/api.js
import axios from 'axios';

const API_URL = 'http://localhost:5000';

export const fetchAbiturients = () => {
    return axios.get(`${API_URL}/abiturients`); // исправленный синтаксис
};

export const createAbiturient = (abiturient) => {
    return axios.post(`${API_URL}/abiturients`, abiturient); // исправленный синтаксис
};

export const updateAbiturient = (id, abiturient) => {
    return axios.put(`${API_URL}/abiturients/${id}`, abiturient); // исправленный синтаксис
};

export const deleteAbiturient = (id) => {
    return axios.delete(`${API_URL}/abiturients/${id}`); // исправленный синтаксис
};

I have the following error:
ERROR
Request failed with status code 404
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404
    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:122693:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:121359:66)
    at Axios.request (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:121846:41)


None of your axios request send through /api/abiturients that you defined in your index.js.Check and correct it

const API_URL = 'http://localhost:5000'
Your backend endpoint is http://localhost:5000/api/abiturients
${API_URL}/abiturients -> This returns http://localhost:5000/abiturients
You are making request to http://localhost:5000/abiturients which does not exists
Update API URL variable with '/api' then you will be able to make requests
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api'

